# CSS is not detected for newly added divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hi I recently added a 404 page to a website found here: http://www.webfounded.com/404.html
The id "greywrap" already existed and CSS detects styles fine, but then **I added "404" "404title" and "404subtitle" classes** and added to the stylesheet but **they are not applying**. This could be just a simple stupid mistake, but having a hard time finding it. Thanks in advance for any help!

HTML

```
        <div id="greywrap" class="404">
        <img src="http://www.webfounded.com/blog/wp-content/themes/ward/library/images/404.png"/>
        <h1 class="404title">404 Error</h1>
        <p class="404subtitle">Sorry. We can't seem to find the page you're looking for.</p>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
.404 {
    padding: 70px 0 60px;
}

.404title {
    margin-top: 100px;
    font-size: 72px;
    line-height: 1.2;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.404subtitle {
    font-size: 38px; 
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

Comment: exactly, css selectors should not start with a number!

Answer (score 0):

According to spec, CSS classes should not begin with integers.  If you are set on using an integer, try escaping it first with \

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I removed numbers completely from the classes and still the issue remains. I have also made sure everything is updated in bootstrap.min.css. I even changed styling of some other existing classes to make sure it is reading stylesheet and it is fine. This one has me stumped! Thanks for any additional help is much appreciated. the page is found at webfounded.com/404.html